# How do I delete additional windows in Mail on iPad?

Tags: mail.app, ipados

[1]Somehow Mail in ipados15 shows multiple windows.

How do I close unwanted windows?

In Mail on startup it shows a number of "windows" towards the bottom of the screen.

Clicking the double box icon shows a number of windows - there is an option to create a new window but there seems to be no option to close them.

In normal operation the other window appears "behind" and the list of Mailboxes and list in selected Mailbox no longer fills screen - the unwanted window appears behind.

NOTE the screenshot only shows the front window  - the unwanted window appears behind and to the right.

[image]

Comment: I would have hoped to see it documented on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207582, but apparently it isn't. AFAIK you can close the additional windows from the switcher.

Answer (score 1):

[Use multitasking on your iPad (Apple)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207582):

> ...swipe up on a thumbnail in the shelf to close that window